# Invoke another exe and get value

Tags: c++

How to invoke another .exe and then get the returned value?

Here's the code that I tried and failed:

```
int main() { 
    int ret = (int) system("Test.exe");  
}
```

In this code ret holds Zero value but it's should be able to container Test.exe's value.

Answer (score 1):

`system` returns OS return code, not the console output. There is no portable way to get the output of the program you run (@Rapptz correction, `system` calls are implementation-defined).

Much easier (at least for some basic usage) would be to redirect output of said `.exe` to a file, and then read that file.

Comment: `system` is not non-standard. It just has an implementation defined return value and implementation-defined semantics.

Comment: `system()` is part of C89 and C99. I'd say that's fairly standard.

Comment: @Hasturkun the question is tagged C++, not C, so C standard is completely not relevant here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Except when it is relevant.  §18.10 says that
`system()` is present in `<cstdlib>`, with the same semantics as in C.  (There are very few, if any standard C functions which are not present in C++, although a couple have slightly different signatures.)

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz if you have any link or tutorial?

Comment: @Md.Mahiuddin See "Definitive C++ Book List" here, on [so].